# Tests fail when creating community user

Tags: apex, soql, unit-test, class

When our unit tests create a new user with the community license, the test fails with the following exception: System.DmlException:

Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: LIMIT_EXCEEDED, limit exceeded: []. 
Test class

```
@isTest
private class UsersSetTest {
  @isTest(SeeAllData=true)
  static void setCompanyNameForCommunityUsers() {
    UserRole portalRole = [SELECT Id FROM UserRole WHERE PortalType = 'None' Limit 1];
    ProfilesData profileData = new ProfilesData();
    Profile communityProfile = profileData.selectProfileByName(CommunitiesExt.PROFILE_CUSTOMER_ACCESS);
    Profile adminProfile = profileData.selectProfileByName('System Administrator');

    User portalAccountOwner1 = new User(
      UserRoleId = portalRole.Id,
      ProfileId = adminProfile.Id,
      Username = System.now().millisecond()+'test2@test.com',
      Alias = 'batman',
      Email='ab@abc.com',
      EmailEncodingKey='UTF-8',
      Firstname='a',
      Lastname='b',
      LanguageLocaleKey='en_US',
      LocaleSidKey='en_US',
      TimeZoneSidKey='America/Chicago'
    );
    insert portalAccountOwner1;

    Contact contact1;
    User user1;
    System.runAs(portalAccountOwner1) {
      //Create account
      Account portalAccount1 = new Account(Name='TestAccount',OwnerId=portalAccountOwner1.Id);
      insert portalAccount1;

      //Create contact
      contact1 = new Contact(FirstName='Test',Lastname='Testy',AccountId=portalAccount1.Id,Email=System.now().millisecond()+'test@test.com');
      insert contact1;

      user1 = SObjectFactory.buildTestUserForProfile(System.now().getTime()+'test@test.com', communityProfile.Id);
      user1.CompanyName = null;
      user1.ContactId = contact1.Id;
      user1.PortalRole = 'Manager';

      insert user1;
    }

    user1 = [SELECT CompanyName FROM User WHERE Id = :user1.Id];
    System.assertEquals(CommunitiesExt.COMPANY_NAME_MEMBER, user1.CompanyName);
  }
}
```

Comment: why `SeeAllData=true`?  does debug log say more about what limit was exceeded?

Comment: @crop1645 I am trying to get the debug log , Although the issue is coming for a particular profile ID

Comment: one thing you could try is to enter the code into anonymous apex (without the runAs) to see if it is related to the test's running user or can be reproduced with you executing the code

Comment: I think you have exceeded the current community user license limit. So try to deactivate any user which you are not using and then run this code.

Comment: Try just running the test without `SeeAllData`. Iirc `runAs` will ignore license limits when creating users.

Comment: What's in the ProfilesData class ?  Is this error from UsersSetTest class or ProfilesData class ?

Comment: @crop1645 there is nothing more than this error. It is coming in the line       insert user1;
Is my Org Portal Roles Limit is marked as 4998 and the max limit 5000 . Is there something similar

Comment: @crop1645 Trying to debug more it is giving me the following error:System.AssertException: Assertion Failed: Failed with status code LIMIT_EXCEEDED         if (A.getStatusCode() != System.StatusCode.UNABLE_TO_LOCK_ROW) {
                        system.assert(false, 'Failed with status code ' + A.getStatusCode());
                    }   here in system.assert line

Comment: cloud lover -- there's too much missing info here to help 1) get rid of seealldata=true; (2) mock everything you need; (3) wrap the `insert user1` with `Test.startTest()..Test.stopTest()` (4) do you have a trigger on User? If so, what does it do (you'll need to expose it in the post)